# MonoTouch - AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException hangs

Tags: multithreading, exception, xamarin.ios

I have a global exception handler that works pretty well in Main.cs, but after catching the error my app doesn't exist, and instead just sort of hangs. I tried Environment.Exit, selector for exit, return, re-throw the exception - all of these still cause a hang. Is there a way to cause the app to terminate? The exception is being throw outside of the main thread.

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += delegate(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            var ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;

            if (!DidReportError)
            {
                var error = ex.GetInnerErrorMessage ();
                Console.WriteLine ("Caught in Main.cs \n\n" + error);
                DidReportError = true;
            }
        };
```

Comment: How are you creating your background threads?  Are you just using `new Thread()` and not setting `IsBackground` to true?

Comment: I'm using ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem is that not the best way to go?

Comment: No, that should exit just fine. I don't see why your code above would hang. Do you just mean it didn't crash? MonoTouch will prevent exceptions on background threads from crashing your app.

Comment: Interesting, is there a way to force quit? Basically the exception happens on a separate thread and the unhandled exception handler catches it and I wasn't the app to close, but at this point it just blocks

Comment: Apple would reject your app if you forced it to exit in any way. Would it be wiser to fix the issue that raised the exception? You shouldn't need a global exception handler like this except for debugging/troubleshooting purposes.

Comment: Right, it's not for catching known issues, it's for when things go wrong unexpectedly for us to get the error report. When that happens the app would have exited anyway. Right now, instead of exiting it just hangs.

Comment: Do you have a try-catch around your `static void Main` method? I would have one there as well, and report the error in the same way.

Comment: I do but that doesn't catch errors in other threads so I have to keep both

Answer (score 0):

You need to figure out why the app hangs, and the easiest way is to create a crash report after the hang [1](http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-crashes-in-monotouch.html):

- Hold down the On/Off button until "slide to power off" appears.
- Release the On/Off button.
- Hold down the Home button.
- After a few seconds the app will be terminated, and a crash report will be generated (the app's exception code will be 0xdeadfa11).

Now you'll find the crash report in Xcode's Organizer (detailed explanation on how to find it [here](http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-crashes-in-monotouch.html)).

[1](http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/native-crashes-in-monotouch.html) http://rolfkvinge.blogspot.com.es/2012/05/monotouch-debugging-tips.html

Comment: Thanks Rolf, though that's not exactly the problem I'm trying to solve. Basically I have an UnhandledException catcher to catch bugs that customers find. But once I record the bug on my end, I want the app to exit, as opposed to hanging forever for the customer. Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: @GregR: The app should abort by itself once you exit the UnhandledException handler.